# Python Scrapy: saving to csv/json does not encode Latin2 properly

Tags: python, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy, and I built a simple spider that scrapes my local news site for titles and amount of comments. It scrapes well, but I have a problem with my language encoding.

I have created a Scrapy project that I then run through anaconda prompt to save the output to a file like so (from the project directory):

`scrapy crawl MySpider -o test.csv`

When I then open the json file with the following code:

```
with open('test.csv', 'r', encoding = "L2") as f:
   file = f.read()
```

I also tried saving it to json, opening in excel, changing to different encodings from [there](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) ... always unreadable, but the characters differ. I am **Czech** if that is relevant. I need characters like ěščřžýáíé etc., but it is Latin.

What I get: Varuje p**Ĺ\x99**ed
What I want: Varuje p**ř**ed

Here is my spider code. I did not change anything in settings or pipeline, though I tried multiple tips from other threads that do this. I spent 2 hours on this already, browsing stack overflow and documentation and I can't find the solution, it's becoming a headache for me. I'm not a programmer so this may be the reason... anyway:

```
urls = []
for number in range(1,101):
    urls.append('https://www.idnes.cz/zpravy/domaci/'+str(number))

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "MySpider"

    def start_requests(self):  
        urls = ['https://www.idnes.cz/zpravy/domaci/']
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse_main)

    def parse_main(self, response):
        articleBlocks = response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"art")]')
        articleLinks = articleBlocks.xpath('.//a[@class="art-link"]/@href')
        linksToFollow = articleLinks.extract()
        for url in linksToFollow:
            yield response.follow(url = url, callback = self.parse_arts)
            print(url)
    
    def parse_arts(self, response):
        for article in response.css('div#content'):
            yield {
                'title': article.css('h1::text').get(),
                'comments': article.css('li.community-discusion > a > span::text').get(),
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy saves feed exports with utf-8 encoding by default.
Opening the file with the correct encoding displays the characters fine.

If you want to change the encoding used, you can do so by using the [`FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feed-export-encoding) setting (or using [`FEEDS`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html#feeds) instead).

Comment: When I run: ```with open('test.csv', 'r', encoding = "utf-8") as f:
    file = f.read()```, I get an error: ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 3605: invalid start byte```

Answer (score 0):

After one more hour of trial and error, I solved this. The problem was not in Scrapy, it was correctly saving in utf-8, the problem was in the command:

`scrapy crawl idnes_spider -o test.csv`

that I ran to save it. When I run the command:

`scrapy crawl idnes_spider -s FEED_URI=test.csv -s FEED_FORMAT=csv`

It works.

Comment: Your original command should work. Otherwise, it may be a bug in Scrapy.